# Docker Build fails

Tags: azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a azure pipeline to restore, build and publish a aspen project and push it in a docker image.

All the steps, restore, build,publish works just fine, but when it the moment to build and publish the docker image, I get the following error

`Error response from daemon: unexpected error reading Dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder340917099: is a directory`

My file structure for the pipeline is configured as follow.
I have a template which looks like:

```
parameters:
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    dotnetCustomArguments: ''
    buildContext: '.'
    dockerfile: ''
    dockerRepository: ''
    dockerRegistry: ''

jobs:
- job: CI
  
  displayName: 'Dotnet Core restore & build'

  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      
  variables:
    buildNumer: "$[variables['Build.BuildNumber']]"
      
  steps:

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'DotNet - Restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '${{ parameters.solution }}'
      noCache: true
      versioningScheme: 'off'
      vstsFeed: 'feeds'
      
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet - Build'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '${{ parameters.solution }}'
      arguments: '${{ parameters.dotnetCustomArguments }}'
      
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'DotNet - Unit tests'
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: 'tests/**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    name: 'DotnetPublish'
    displayName: 'dotnet - Publish'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '${{ parameters.solution }}'
      arguments: '${{ parameters.dotnetCustomArguments }}'
      modifyOutputPath: false
      zipAfterPublish: false
      publishWebProjects: false

  - task: Docker@2
    name: 'dockerBuildAndPush'
    displayName: 'docker - Build & Push'
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: '${{ parameters.dockerRegistry }}'
      repository: '${{ parameters.dockerRepository }}'
      Dockerfile: '${{ parameters.dockerfile }}'
      buildContext: '${{ parameters.buildContext }}'
      tags: |
        $(Build.BuildNumber)
        latest
```

And I have the actual pipeline trigger that uses this template for all the steps

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry

trigger:
    branches:
      include:
      - development
  
variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '<service-connection'
  imageRepository: '<image-repos>'
  containerRegistry: 'container-registry'
  dockerfilePath: 'path-to-/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Code build'
  jobs: 
  - job: Build & Publish
  - template: azure-pipelines/dotnetcore-build.yaml
    parameters:
      solution: 'path-to-.csproj'
      dockerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
      dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
      dockerRepository: $(imageRepository)
      dotnetCustomArguments: '-o publish/project -c release'
```

The error occurs on the last step of the template `Build & Push`

EDIT:

this is my tree structure

```
 My.Folder.Api
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── my.file.Api.csproj
│   ├── my.file.Api.sln
│   ├── Program.cs
│   ├── Properties
│   │   └── launchSettings.json
│   ├── Startup.cs
│   ├── appsettings.api.Development.json
│   ├── appsettings.api.json
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── Debug
│   │       └── netcoreapp3.1
│   └── obj
│       └── Debug
│           └── netcoreapp3.1
│               └──my.Api.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
 azure-pipeline.yaml
```

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your docker file path. You can try to specify `**/Dockerfile` value in the `Dockerfile` parameter of the docker task.

Comment: if I use **/Dockerfile technically it will look for all the docker files I have in the subfolders right? but as I have 2 folders with 2 docker files..I need it to target only that specific one and not all of them

Comment: Yes, then please check if the path you specified in the `dockerfile` parameter is correct, can you share the value of this parameter with us for testing

Comment: I did multiple time and just refused to read it. this is the structure of the folder starting from the root.
```
> MyFolder
    |- > Dockerfile
> azure-pipeline.yaml
```

so from the azure pipeline I should go into Myfolder and my docker file is there

Comment: ill update the post with the tree structure